# How can I get the raw MMS message on an Android device

Tags: android, mms, smil

I'm trying to debug the SMIL layouts being sent by the carriers to the handset. There doesn't appear to be a way to save or view the raw message received by the device. Does anyone know of:

1. A way to save or view raw MMS messages from the default messaging app?
2. An app on the market that can provide this visibility?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556633/parse-application-smil-mms-mime-type-on-android

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?  Trying to do the same thing in 2015 :)

Comment: I never did @MikeJansen.